# unknown pop-ups show 0

Tags: support

there is the **unknown pop-ups show 0** in my website.

Last time I edit my website is 1 month ago,and it still didn’t have that .

In this period of time , I only update the wordpress and plugin.
I don’t know why this happening,

Can anybody help me?

The page I need help with: https://www.hueming.com.tw/

Comment: Have you tried disabling all of your plugins and switching to a default theme? This usually identifies what is adding the code. Since you're using Google Tag Manager you may also want to disable that and see whether the alert is there.

Comment: This looks like a generic javascript issue, look for calls to the `alert` function in your sites javascript. Disable every plugin then re-enable one by one to identify which one is the culprit

Comment: It seems this line is the cause: `alert(jQuery('body').find('.wpfm-menu-wrapper').attr('data-disable-double-touch'));` but because you used autoptimise I can't identify the plugin/file it comes from, Autoptimize smushes it all together Perhaps, the `wpfm` accronym is a clue?

Comment: If I disable it, Can you help tome find where is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps, the `wpfm` accronym is a clue? Identify which plugin wpfm stands for then open an issue with their support, 3rd party plugin support is offtopic and not allowed on this site

Comment: I have already disable it.

Comment: I think that one is the Contact Form 7 or the other one is for verify the phone number when they submit the form, The plugin maker say their is something wrong when I use my theme so he change script for me and it works at that time

Comment: I have used the Debug mode,When I turn on all of the plugin there is nothing happend, So , should this be the theme's problem?

Comment: Can you check this page?  https://www.hueming.com.tw/siemens/siemens-sentron-busway/    I found that there is only some page will happend now! In which have the contact form